# How do I list new drives so I can partition and format them?

Tags: server, partitioning, hard-drive

I added a bunch of drives to an external enclosure and attached it to a server via eSATA and now need to get them ready for software raid. However they do not appear under `fdisk -l`

I've tried looking in `/dev/disk/by-path` and `/dev/disk/by-id`. The RAID card appears in dmesg. Plugging and unplugging the eSATA enclosure does not cause anything to "happen" when I tail `/var/log/syslog`

There is a decent chance that the eSATA card I am using in the machine is faulty (I found it laying around). But before I purchase a new one I want to make sure I am not missing anything obvious.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try running the command `ls /dev/sd*`.

This should list all drives on the system with their device names. Compare that to the output of `fdisk -l` which will show the current list if you don't know which are which.

Comment: It was indeed hardware but I used this to confirm, thanks!

Comment: Don't forget to `sudo fdisk -l`

Answer (score 18):

Run `parted` interactively, then use the `print devices` command, like below:

```
sudo parted
GNU Parted 2.3
Using /dev/xvda1
Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
(parted) print devices                                                    
/dev/xvda1 (8590MB)
/dev/xvdb (429GB)
```

Answer (score 12):

In Ubuntu, the command `fdisk -l` doesn't return anything because it is not proceeded by sudo. Do: `sudo fdisk -l` and it should return information about your disks.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 128.0 GB, 128035676160 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 15566 cylinders, total 250069680 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1               1   250069679   125034839+  ee  GPT
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a graphical install, then  **GParted** is the way to go (in the Software Centre).

Comment: server, check the tag. :)